# How to light a candle with small amounts of safe to use chemicals?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, heat

Already saw some youtube video where they lit a camp fire with glycerol and potassium permanganate and tried those but the amount of the stuff you need to create enough heat is just too much.

So is there a way to light a candle with small amount of something and something, like having the candle wick dipped/powdered with something and then just letting it get into contact with something else?

Comment: Well, you could coat the head of the candle with phosphorous and then scrape it against a rough surface...but that would basically be a match.

Comment: What is wrong with matches? A small amount of chemicals applied to a small stick to create fire in a safe way...

Answer (score 2):

Safety and ability to light a fire, as far as I understand, directly contradict each other. What starts a fire on your wish, would occasionally start a fire against your wish. The glycerol/sulfuric acid/permanganate recipe, like it or not, is probably the safest of all.

Others include:

- [White phosphorus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allotropes_of_phosphorus#White_phosphorus), not only flammable but also severely toxic by itself.
- [Butyllithium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tert-Butyllithium#Safety) and many other organometallic compounds that would ignite instantly on air; that's not quite what you want, anyway.
- Hydrogen against [platinum black](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platinum_black#Catalytic_ignition_of_flammable_gasses) (danger of explosion).

I definitely would not try any of these at home.